# Conditions of mixage/remix of an old music track

Tags: jazz, copyrights

I am an amateur musician and I would like to do some mixage (partial exploitation, such as a melody) or remix of some Jazz oldies and publish them in YouTube.

I don't earn money from this (no video monetizing) so I don't envisage spending money (on copyright), except on the DAW.

Are there conditions? What are they if any? For example: the minimum age of the music?

Comment: "The minimum age of a music" ...for the song to be out of copyright, 70 years after the composer's death. The recorded performance, though, may never go out of copyright, as it belongs to a continuing company.

Comment: You could try to have your work fall under fair use, but be careful with that and preferably consult a lawyer if you're unsure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because legal issues are off topic.

Comment: Copyright law questions like this are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube automatically scans videos for copyright violations, which can be either good or bad for you depending on what material you use. Depending on their agreement with the copyright owner, YouTube will either take the video down or direct the ad revenue to the copyright owner. So you can post your works to YouTube, but understand that they might get taken down.